# mousedown event is not continous and runs for a single time only

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mousedown

I am trying to draw a wall-like structure. Let me explain: when mousedown event occurs that cell will become a wall (I'll add some color say black) and unless the mouseup event occurs all the cells through where the cursor will pass will also become a wall. Currently, I am only able to make one wall by mousedown event. Any suggestions or advice would be highly appreciated.

```js
var gridCols = 60;
var gridRows = Math.floor(screen.height / 25) - 2;
gridContainer.style.left = (screen.width-25*gridCols)/screen.width * 50+"%";
var found = false;
const WALLCOLOR = "black", STARTCOLOR = "red", STOPCOLOR="green", VISITEDCOLOR="magenta",
CURRENTCOLOR="yellow"; // Try to implement arrow direction


function sleep(ms) 
{
 return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

function getCell(row, col)
{
 return document.querySelector(".row:nth-child("+(row+1)+") .gridsquare:nth-child("+(col+1)+")");
}


function addWall(row, col)
{
 getCell(row, col).style.background = WALLCOLOR;
}


function genDivs(rows, cols)
{ 
 var e = document.getElementById("gridContainer");
 for(var r = 0; r < rows; r++)
 { 
  var row = document.createElement("div"); 
  row.className = "row";
  for(var c = 0; c < cols; c++)
  { 
   var cell = document.createElement("div"); 
   if(r == 10 && c == 20)
    cell.style.background = STARTCOLOR;
   else if(r == 10 && c == 40)
    cell.style.background = STOPCOLOR;
      
      cell.className = "gridsquare"; 
      cell.addEventListener("mousedown", addWall.bind(null, r, c));
      row.appendChild(cell); 
  } 
  e.appendChild(row); 
 }
}


function clearGrid()
{
 for(var i=0; i<20; i++) 
 {
     for(var j=0; j<60; j++) 
     {
      if(i == 10 && j == 20)
          getCell(i, j).style.background = STARTCOLOR;
         else if(i == 10 && j == 40)
          getCell(i, j).style.background = STOPCOLOR;
         else 
          getCell(i, j).style.background = "white";
         getCell(i, j).classList.remove("animateCell");
     }

 }
}

genDivs(20, gridCols);
console.log(found);
//dfs(11, 20);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <style>
  #gridContainer
  {
   outline: 1px solid rgb(175, 216, 248);
   font-size: 0;
   position: absolute;
  }
  .row
  {
   
  }
  .gridsquare
  {
   width: 25px;
   height: 25px;
   box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgb(175, 216, 248) inset, 1px 0px 0px rgb(175, 216, 248) inset;
   display: inline-block;
  }
  .begin
  {
   background-color: purple;
  }
  .end
  {
   background-color: magenta;
  }
  .animateCell
  {
   box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgb(237, 12, 0) inset, 1px 0px 0px rgb(237, 12, 0) inset;
   background-color: yellow;
   animation-name: stretch;
   animation-duration: 1.5s; 
   animation-timing-function: ease-out; 
   animation-delay: 0;
   animation-fill-mode: none;
  }

  @keyframes stretch 
  {
   0% 
   {
    transform: scale(.0);
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 100%;
   }
   50% 
   {
    background-color: orange;
   }
   80% 
   {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    background-color: pink;

   }
   100%
   {
    transform: scale(1)
    background-color: pink;
   }
  }
  button
  {
   position: absolute;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="gridContainer"></div>
 <!-- <button type = "button" onclick="DFSUtil(10, 20)"> Click </button> --> 
 <!-- <button type = "button" onclick="BFSUtil(10, 20)"> Click </button> -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="HomeScript.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="./Algorithms/DepthFirstSearch.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="./Algorithms/BreadthFirstSearch.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you're looking for painting divs grid

```js
let canvas = document.querySelector("#container"),
  isDragging = false;

canvas.onmousedown = function(e) {
  if(e.target.nodeName === "DIV" && !e.target.id) {
    e.target.className = "black";
    isDragging = true;
  }
}

canvas.onmouseup = canvas.onmouseleave = function() {
  isDragging = false;
}

document.body.ondragstart = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}

canvas.onmouseover = function(e) {
  if(isDragging && e.target.nodeName === "DIV" && !e.target.id) {
    e.target.className = "black";
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 300px;
}
#container div {
  border: 1px solid cyan;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  border-bottom: none;
}
.black {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: After some tiny change in the above code, I got it working (smooth and gracious). Thanks gentleman

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to listen for mousemove events after the mousedown event and before the mouseup event :), (edited)

```js
let canvas = document.querySelector("canvas"),
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
  isDragging = false, cellSize = 25;

function drawRect(x, y, xl, yl, c) {
  ctx.fillStyle = c;
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, xl, yl);
}

function makeGrid(val, color, width, height) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  for(var x = 0; x <= height; x += val) {
    ctx.moveTo(0, x);
    ctx.lineTo(width, x);
    ctx.strokeStyle = color;
    ctx.stroke();
  }

  for(var y = 0; y <= width; y += val) {
    ctx.moveTo(y, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(y, height);
    ctx.strokeStyle = color;
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}

canvas.onmousedown = function(e) {
  let x = e.offsetX - e.offsetX % cellSize,
    y = e.offsetY - e.offsetY % cellSize;
    drawRect(x, y, cellSize, cellSize, "red");
  isDragging = true;
}

canvas.onmouseup = canvas.onmouseout = function() {
  isDragging = false;
}

canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
  let x = e.offsetX - e.offsetX % cellSize,
    y = e.offsetY - e.offsetY % cellSize;
  if(isDragging) {
    drawRect(x, y, cellSize, cellSize, "red");
  }
}

makeGrid(cellSize, "blue", canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

```css
canvas {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<canvas width="300" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: Is it better to register `onmousemove` listener once and run it all the time or add it in `onmousedown` and remove in `onmouseup`?

Comment: nope only once, just like in my example, since onmousemove will not paint unless isDragging is true which is controlled by onmousedown and up, and you can accept my post as an answer, so anyone asks the same question finds it, happy coding :)

Comment: If I am able to track through which cell of the grid, the cursor is moving upon onmousemove, it should work in my case. Let me know if you have any approach.

Comment: Go write your own code, and if it didn't work I will help you :)

Comment: Well how am I supposed to get the cell through where the crusor is moving @SaymoinSam

Comment: what is the width and height of the cell and it's coords, I mean cells rect coords and not mouse coords

Comment: Well as I already said the best I could do was mousedown event worked once for a cell. I needed it continous

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211379/discussion-between-abhishek-and-saymoinsam).

Comment: yes I know but to do that you need some calculations, I will update my code to make a small grid of cells and show you how to, wait maybe 5 or 10 minutes

Comment: I do understand your approach and appreciate your effort, but I think I will need the cells in form of grid of divs itself.

Comment: But why are you using divs?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=17Ic1D0vUdUV5hU26SyTjrxl8nzIYbDih You can refer the above link. I need divs to animate them, see for yourself. But yeah thanks man, really appreciate your help.